# api call error 403 microsoft teams messages

Tags: power-automate, microsoft-graph-teams

I created a Microsoft Flow that read channels in teams and it works (`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{Teamsid}/channels`).

Now I need to create a new one that read message from a channel with the same account as before. I put an HTTP request:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{Teamsid}/channels/{channelid}/messages`

My request works in Graph explorer but in flow get answer: `forbidden`

Body:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "da5d3795-86f8-4f70-ade0-2d88493b7ea0",
      "date": "2019-07-09T12:53:06"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-protected-apis

Microsoft Teams APIs in Microsoft Graph that access sensitive data are considered protected APIs. These APIs require that you have additional validation, beyond permissions and consent, before you can use them.

The following APIs are currently protected:

- List channel messages using application permissions
- Get channel message using application permissions
- List replies to a message using application permissions
- Get a reply to a message using application permissions
- List messages in a chat using application permissions
- Get message in chat using application permissions